# "keep in touch" VS " keep the lines of communication open"

Tags: differences

Is there any difference between  "keep in touch" and " keep the lines of communication open"?

Answer (score 2):

"Keep in touch" is much more informal, and possibly would sound more friendly.

"Keep the lines of communication open" is very formal sounding, and almost aloof. It is a more of a command, as compared to "Keep in touch", which is a friendly way of saying you would like to communicate more with that person.